# Forge Create Activity Gives Bad Request

Tags: autodesk-forge, autodesk-designautomation

Using DA for Revit on Autodesk Forge.  I have my code created and tested locally and am trying to deploy it to a testing application but hit a bit of a snag and not sure where I'm going wrong.  I have created the Forge App, created and uploaded the bundle, created an alias for the bundle, but now am trying to create an activity and it's returning a bad request but not sure why.

I'm using Insomnia for my testing so here is the timeline readout for my request (with tokens, etc. removed):

```
* Preparing request to https://developer.api.autodesk.com/da/us-east/v3/activities
* Using libcurl/7.57.0-DEV OpenSSL/1.0.2o zlib/1.2.11 libssh2/1.7.0_DEV
* Current time is 2020-05-05T18:30:00.962Z
* Disable timeout
* Enable automatic URL encoding
* Enable SSL validation
* Enable cookie sending with jar of 3 cookies
* Connection 31 seems to be dead!
* Closing connection 31
*   Trying 52.21.0.245...
* TCP_NODELAY set
* Connected to developer.api.autodesk.com (52.21.0.245) port 443 (#32)
* ALPN, offering http/1.1
* Cipher selection: ALL:!EXPORT:!EXPORT40:!EXPORT56:!aNULL:!LOW:!RC4:@STRENGTH
* successfully set certificate verify locations:
*   CAfile: **removed**
*   CApath: none
* TLSv1.2 (OUT), TLS header, Certificate Status (22):
* TLSv1.2 (OUT), TLS handshake, Client hello (1):
* TLSv1.2 (IN), TLS handshake, Server hello (2):
* TLSv1.2 (IN), TLS handshake, Certificate (11):
* TLSv1.2 (IN), TLS handshake, Server key exchange (12):
* TLSv1.2 (IN), TLS handshake, Server finished (14):
* TLSv1.2 (OUT), TLS handshake, Client key exchange (16):
* TLSv1.2 (OUT), TLS change cipher, Client hello (1):
* TLSv1.2 (OUT), TLS handshake, Finished (20):
* TLSv1.2 (IN), TLS change cipher, Client hello (1):
* TLSv1.2 (IN), TLS handshake, Finished (20):
* SSL connection using TLSv1.2 / ECDHE-RSA-AES128-GCM-SHA256
* ALPN, server did not agree to a protocol
* Server certificate:
*  subject: businessCategory=Private Organization; jurisdictionC=US; jurisdictionST=Delaware; serialNumber=2401504; C=US; ST=California; L=San Rafael; O=Autodesk, Inc.; OU=MCP-ASRD-CP; CN=developer.api.autodesk.com
*  start date: Feb 24 00:00:00 2020 GMT
*  expire date: Mar 22 12:00:00 2021 GMT
*  subjectAltName: host "developer.api.autodesk.com" matched cert's "developer.api.autodesk.com"
*  issuer: C=US; O=DigiCert Inc; OU=www.digicert.com; CN=DigiCert SHA2 Extended Validation Server CA
*  SSL certificate verify ok.

> POST /da/us-east/v3/activities HTTP/1.1
> Host: developer.api.autodesk.com
> User-Agent: insomnia/7.1.1
> Cookie: PF=**removed**
> Content-Type: application/json
> Authorization: Bearer **removed**
> Accept: */*
> Content-Length: 592

| {
|   "id":"RunChecks",
|   "commandLine":["$(engine.path)\\\\revitcoreconsole.exe /i $(args[rvtFile].path) /al $(appbundles[ModelChecker].path)"],
|   "paremeters": {
|       "rvtFile": {
|           "zip": false,
|           "ondemand": false,
|           "verb": "get",
|           "description": "Input Revit Model",
|           "required":true,
|           "localName": "$(rvtFile)"
|       },
|       "result": {
|           "zip": false,
|           "ondemand": false,
|           "verb": "put",
|           "description": "Results",
|           "required":true,
|           "localName": "Report.xml"
|       }
|   },
|   "engine": "Autodesk.Revit+2021",
|   "appbundles": ["BIT.ModelChecker+dev"],
|   "description":"Runs model checks"
| }

* upload completely sent off: 592 out of 592 bytes

< HTTP/1.1 400 Bad Request
< Content-Type: application/json; charset=utf-8
< Date: Tue, 05 May 2020 18:30:01 GMT
< Strict-Transport-Security: max-age=31536000; includeSubDomains
< Via: 1.1 824fe21e467658628899bdd8725649ee.cloudfront.net (CloudFront)
< x-amz-apigw-id: MEiKjFSroAMF20A=
< X-Amz-Cf-Id: mwq0J1Q567VwiT7nGfKuSPdrctm5Cv-AxbVpV6KhA6ZbZiTM-mAkCw==
< X-Amz-Cf-Pop: IAD89-C1
< x-amzn-Remapped-Content-Length: 90
< x-amzn-RequestId: 761a452d-2bde-4e8f-987c-fb9d4f25ce7b
< X-Amzn-Trace-Id: Root=1-5eb1b0a9-b01c07c62357bb2604081bf6
< X-Cache: Error from cloudfront
< Content-Length: 90
< Connection: keep-alive


* Received 90 B chunk
* Connection #32 to host developer.api.autodesk.com left intact
```

The response is a 400 with the following body:

```
{
  "commandLine": [
    "Value cannot be null. (Parameter 'source')\n (Parameter 'commandLine')"
  ]
}
```

I pulled this from the example [here](https://forge.autodesk.com/en/docs/design-automation/v3/tutorials/revit/step5-publish-activity/) and just modified to use my own aliases, etc.

I see that it says `source` and `commandLine` can not be null but `source` isn't mentioned anywhere in the documentation that I can find and isn't in the example so I'm not sure what it is and `commandLine` is set just like the example...

Where am I going wrong?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have a typo in the activity definition. 
The field `parameters` is misspelt as `paremeters`.

(We can improve our error reporting)